# Can an U2F public/private key-pair for signatures be used for encryption?

Tags: encryption, public-key, signature, protocol-design

I understand that this might be more a process question:

Given a [U2F device](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-u2f-v1.1-id-20160915/fido-u2f-overview-v1.1-id-20160915.html) which supports signatures using ECDSA public/private key pairs, is there a way to use the signing function of such a device to generate an encryption key?

I would like to understand if U2F could be used to improve the following scenario:

- I use a password manager with a password vault file with 100 stored passwords.
- I use a master secret to unlock the password vault, which leads the password manager to decrypt all 100 passwords.
- I use a single password from the vault to log into a web-site and close the vault again.
- An attacker that has access to my computer would have access to the master password, the password vault file and all 100 passwords.

How can we improve on this scenario:

- I would like to encrypt each password stored in the vault with a specific encryption key.
- I would like to use a second factor device to make sure that only one password is decrypted at a time when I perform a physical action.
- U2F seems an ideal application for this, since it automates the process of storing individual credentials for individual 'sites', except that it performs signatures but not encryption.

Constraints:

- The public/private key pair is generated inside the U2F device and the private key can not leave the device.
- The device does not support any other operations but the signature operations based on the [U2F specification](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-u2f-v1.0-nfc-bt-amendment-20150514/fido-u2f-raw-message-formats.html), namely ECDSA.
- The password vault should be treated as an insecure and static, i.e. the user has unlocked the vault and an attacker could see all data in it. The password manager has no means to perform any secret operation, any computation is visible to an attacker.
- Communication between password manager and U2F device can be observed entirely by the attacker.

Pointers:

- [A comment in an answer to a similar question on security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/99787/141681) seems to indicate that there is no plausible way to use an ECDSA device to derive an encryption scheme

To answer @fgrieu's question:

- The U2F device is meant to assist to decrypt a single encrypted password
- An authentication scheme is not sufficient, since an attacker has access to all encrypted data and could bypass the authentication step if no encryption is involved.
- Only a signature function exists on the U2F device
- The U2F protocol is executed by the password manager as the server, so no external data storage exists. All U2F handle information and the ECDSA public-key are to be stored in the password vault.
- The U2F device generates public/private key-pairs of which the public-key is returned as part of the initial registration. The private key remains securely stored on the U2F device.

Comment: U2F by itself is an authentication protocol, if you have direct access to the primitives required for the protocol things may be possible though.

Comment: The question is assuming that I have a U2F device that I could interact with in any way the U2F specification says the device must be capable of.

Comment: Are you asking whether it is possible to use U2F's ECDSA ([see here](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-u2f-v1.0-nfc-bt-amendment-20150514/fido-u2f-raw-message-formats.html)) signature of some piece of data as an encryption key?

Comment: @mrwhythat Yes, that would be the question. Can we design an encryption protocol around such as a signature.

Comment: Well, ECDSA, as most signature algorithms is randomized with special value $k$ and a security requirement that each signature is produced with different $k$, because otherwise, having two signatures with the same $k$ allows for computing signer's private key (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) for more details).

Comment: Would the U2F device act as 1) encryption device for some secret message? 2) decryption device for the resulting cryptogram ? 3) compute engine on the client side of a password-based authentication and key agreement protocol (à la SRP), which is not the same as 1 ? 4) as a safeguard in case of leak of password-authenticating data, on the server side of a similar protocol? Tick all that apply. For 1, why would you need an U2F device at all, since public key encryption requires no long-term secret? Who's "given a ECDSA public/private key pair": the U2F device, its user, some other party?

Comment: I was hoping that the signature $(r,s)$ could be used as a starting point for an encryption scheme using the signatures properties such as `r === x1 mod n`.

Comment: @fgrieu I tried to answer in the text: I think that the U2F device can only perform signatures and that I was hoping that it should be possible to derive a decryption key from a protocol using such signatures. So 3) comes closest. U2F devices cannot do 1) and 2) because they can only perform signatures. 4) does not apply because there is no server.

Comment: Would it be accurate to sum up the functional goal as: use the U2F device as a hardware key to a conventional-password manager on a user's computer, with security goal that use of the device _before_ getting hold of the password manager's database won't reveal the passwords? And would it be OK that the device is required to enter a new password ? If so, it would be good enough to turn an ECDSA signature device into a _symmetric_ encryption device; something that the linked [comment](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/99787/141681) does not rule out.

Comment: Yes, usage of the device *before* an attacker gets hold of the database should not lead to any loss of passwords. Yes, the device would be necessary to enter a new password into the vault (encrypt it). Yes, symmetric encryption would be enough. Sum up: Can we derive a encryption key (any) from an ECDSA scheme?

Comment: I suspect it might be possible to encrypt a random N-bit key using a U2F device, by ensuring that for each bit in the key a U2F challenge either succeeds (1) or fails (0). One way to do this might be to abuse the application-ids. However, I'm not familiar enough with U2F yet to be sure it would work.

Answer (score 3):

No.

It is possible to derive keys from deterministic signatures (or non-deterministic signatures that can be converted into a deterministic value), for example Android [uses Trusted Execution Environment's RSA signing plus scrypt to bind Full Disk Encryption keys](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/full-disk) to a specific device.

However, ECDSA signatures are not deterministic (there's [RFC6979](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6979), which specifies deterministic use, but U2F doesn't use it), so each generated signature will be different for the same message and key, thus you cannot derive the same key from multiple signings.

Comment: I find the conclusion very plausible. However the _"thus"_ lacks mathematical rigor. An hypothetical textbook-RSA-signing-like black box that accepts $m$ with $0<m<N$, and outputs $(r,s)$ with random $r$ ($0<r<N$ and $\gcd(r,N)=1$) and $s=x^d\;r\bmod N$ (perhaps computed as $s=(r^e\;x)^d\bmod N$ internally) generates different signatures for the same message and key, yet can be efficiently turned into a deterministic RSA deciphering device with a little external code.

Comment: @fgrieu: If it can be turned into a deterministic RSA device, wouldn't it be possible to use it for the intended purpose?

Comment: @Christopher Oezbek: that's my point. A deciphering device is just what the question asks, and the reasoning in the answer does not satisfactorily demonstrate that the U2F device can't be transformed into that with some clever math. Still, I'm also inclined to believe that it can't be done.

Comment: I think this article disagrees with your conclusion: https://jbp.io/2015/11/23/abusing-u2f-to-store-keys.html However, I am not competent enough to understand if the described method is sound or not